# jqGrid sort index by column name

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Simple question. Is there a function to get the current sort position of a column by name in a grid?

Comment: Do you mean the index of the column in `colModel` by which the grid are sorted?

Comment: yeah, I am trying to use remapColumns to change the order. I am have a list of the new sort order based on the name of the column but I need to get the indexes. I cannot seem to get it to march up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexes used in the `remapColumns` method are the same as in the `colModel` array. It's important to understand, that the indexes can be different as in the `colModel` parameter of jqGrid used initially. If jqGrid uses options `rownumbers: true` an additional column with the name `'rn'` will be inserted at the first place of `colModel` array. The indexes of all other elements of `colModel` array will be incremented. In the same way the option `multiselect: true` inserts the column `'cb'` abd the option `subGrid: true` inserts the column `'subgrid'`. In the same way the option `treeGrid: true` follows appending `colModel` array with some additional hidden columns which names can be defined by `treeReader`. The default names of the columns in case of `treeGridModel: 'nested'` are: `'level'`, `'lft'`, `'rgt'`, `'isLeaf'`, `'expanded'`, `'loaded'` and `'icon'` or `'level'`, `'parent'`, `'isLeaf'`, `'expanded'`, `'loaded'` and `'icon'` in case of `treeGridModel: 'adjacency'`.

So to find the index of the column by the name you should just get the current `colModel`, look through the items and find the item where `'name'` property are the column name which you need. To get `colModel` you can use `$("#grid")[0].p.colModel` or `$("#grid").jqGrid('getgridParam', 'colModel')`. So the code can be like the following:

```
var getColumnIndexByName = function (columnName) {
        var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                return i; // return the index
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };
```

and the usage like

```
var $grid = $("#grid"),
    iCol = getColumnIndexByName.call($grid[0], 'myColName');
```

To get the name of the current sorted column you can use `$grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname')`

Comment: Thanks again for your help. This worked great. I knew that I could not do this using the original order of the colModel. I noticed that the rownumbers added another column and like you explained there are a lot of other ways it will not be the same. Again this worked perfect though. Thanks again.