# how to delete the contents of a particular column of jqgrid table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

how to delete the contents of a particular column of all the rows of jqgrid table?

or how can i set a particular column of all the rows of jqgrid table with a particular value in a single shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

To delete contents:

```
$('td[aria-describedby=<your table name>_<column name>]').html('');
```

To set a value:

```
$('td[aria-describedby=<your table name>_<column name>]').html('whatever');
```

Comment: i am sorry i was precise in asking the question. i cant understand

Comment: table name = "tab", column name='col1' but what about aria-describedby. what i understood is your code is forming a id, but how '=' comes under the id

Comment: you need to check [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), that's for selecting an element with an attribute with the specified value, td is to select the td elements, aria-describedby is the attribute assiged automatically by jqgrid, whose value would be in your case "tab_col1", so the selector would be `$('td[aria-describedby=<tab_col1>_<column name>]')` (so in this case you don't need the id)

Comment: Great I'm glad, if that's the answer you expected it'd be nice if you set it as the accepted answer...

Comment: I don't wanted to write my comments before the answer was accepted. A little more effective will be 1) to get the index of the column like it is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9580376/315935)  2) use `$("#grid").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child("+(pos+1)+")").empty()` where `pos` is 0-based index of column returned by `getColumnIndexByName`.